# AngularJS не генерирует список из JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Решил изучать AngularJS и потребовалось послать запрос на скрипт который возвращает JSON, далее из этого JSON генерируется список **Li**

**JSON от сервера:**

```
[{"id":"1","title":"\u0413\u043e\u0432\u044f\u0434\u0438\u043d\u0430","description":"","pos":"1","approved":"1"},{"id":"2","title":"\u041a\u0443\u0440\u0438\u0446\u0430","description":"","pos":"2","approved":"1"},{"id":"3","title":"\u0411\u0430\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043d\u0430","description":"","pos":"3","approved":"1"},{"id":"4","title":"\u041f\u043e\u043b\u0443\u0444\u0430\u0431\u0440\u0438\u043a\u0430\u0442\u044b","description":"","pos":"4","approved":"1"},{"id":"5","title":"\u041d\u0430\u043f\u0438\u0442\u043a\u0438","description":"","pos":"5","approved":"1"},{"id":"6","title":"\u041d\u0430\u043f\u0438\u0442\u043a\u0438","description":"","pos":"6","approved":"1"}]
```

**Controller:**

```
var CategoryController = angular.module('CategoryController',[]);

CategoryController.controller('MakeCategories', function($scope){

    $.get('http://api.site.com/categories',function(data){

        $scope.categories = data;

    });

});
```

Заранее оповещаю, что юзаю **$.get**, так как **$http.get** посылает **OPTIONS**, даже если я указываю метод GET при вызове метода **$http()**. И никак не послать запрос на свой поддомен.

**Сам HTML код:**

```
    <div class="col-2 clearfix" ng-app="CategoryController">

    <div class="panel-header clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-3"><h1>Категории</h1></div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <button id="add-cat-btn" onclick="Category.CreateItem();" class="add-cat-btn">Добавить категорию</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-content" ng-controller="MakeCategories">

        <div class="panel-order-table cat-table">

            <div class="panel-cat-header">
                <span>НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ</span>
            </div>

            <ul class="panel-cat-list white-block">
              <li ng-repeat="cat in categories">
                <span id="drag-icon-block">
                    <span class="sprite-icon drag-icon"></span>
                </span>
                <span id="cat-item-label">{{cat.title}}</span>
                <div id="cat-item-btns">
                    <span onclick="Category.Edit({{cat.id}});" class="sprite-icon edit"></span>
                    <span class="sprite-icon delete"></span>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Но ничего не выводит. В чем может быть проблема? Я только начал переходить на JS фреймворки.

Comment: смотрите ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: Там пусто. Я проверял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как используется не встроенный механизм запросов, то ангуляр не знает что запрос выполнился и данные нужно синхронизировать с view.

Для этого можно использовать [$scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), либо сервис [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Например так:

```
CategoryController.controller('MakeCategories', function($scope){

    $.get('http://api.site.com/categories',function(data){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.categories = data;
        });
    });

});
```